# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (swipe nav)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this question has already been asked many times, but I checked all the possible issues in the various answers and it still doesn't work.

I'm trying to add a custom cell to a table view, but this error message appears and the app crashes:

`Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is the code of the view controller where I added the table view:

```
import UIKit

class VC0: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var names = ["Artist name", "Artist Name", "Artist name", "Artist name", "Artist name", "Artist name"]
var cities = ["City", "City", "City", "City", "City", "City"]
var images = [UIImage(named: "avatar"), UIImage(named: "avatar1"), UIImage(named: "avatar2"), UIImage(named: "avatar3"), UIImage(named: "avatar4"), UIImage(named: "avatar5")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTableView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.city.text = cities[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}

}
```

The error appears on this line :

```
cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
```

Here is the project if you want to take a look at the full code : http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/frhaniuw5e36xej/swipeViews%20-%20copie.zip?dl=0

Comment: Get rid of your implicitly unwrapped optionals and force unwraps.  And if you want help on [so], you need to post your actual code, not a link to download a zip of your code which is definitely your code, definitely not a virus, and definitely not ever going to rot.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to post the code here, it was just to check everything including the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `registerClass` is overwriting your creation of the prototype cell in your storyboard. From the `UITableView` documentation:

> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry.

Instead, you're creating new, blank, instances of `CustomCell`, which doesn't have your outlets hooked up. Remove that line, and things should work.